# How to add AND OR in elasticsearch query?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a query where the user can search for a specific product. The query works with 1 condition but when I add another condition it gives me an empty array.

What I'm looking for using SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE shop = "shop" AND  title like "%dogs%"
```

Example with 1 condition

```
GET /products/_search?size=25&from=50
{
    "query": {
         "bool": {
             "must": [
                   {"match_phrase": {"shop": "xxxxx.myshopify.com"}}
             ]
         }
     }
 }
```

/products/_mapping

```
{
  "products" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "body_html" : {
          ...
        },
        "created_at" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "handle" : {
          ...
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "image" : {
          ...
        },
        "images" : {
          ...
        },
        "shop" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your mapping?

Comment: @ryanlutgen Hello sir. I just updated my question check it

Comment: If you take a look at the official documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/combining-filters.html#_nesting_boolean_queries the ElasticSearch API uses different terms for and, or and not. You can also nest them, to create more complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

Something as follows may work:

```
GET /products/_search?size=25&from=50
{
    "query": {
         "bool": {
             "must": [
                   {"term": {"shop": "xxxxx.myshopify.com"}},
                   {"match": {"title": "dogs"}},
             ]
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed my final query looks like this. BUT I removed paging.  Sometimes it can affect the search, what you are looking for not available for this range size=x&from=x

Answer (score 0):

For the `like` part a [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) query would do the trick.

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "shop": "xxxxx.myshopify.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "title": {
              "value": "*dog*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```